# Routing two private networks over Internet

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

Good day,

A bit of "background":
I have 15+ servers over 3 DataCenters. Each have a public IP, and each server inside a Datacenter is also connected to a VLAN, so 3 VLANs. Each of these servers will, in time, only have the VLAN interface.

Basically, I'd want any X server (192.168.1.3/24) on DC1 to be able to access Y server (192.168.2.5/24) on DC2.
I do not have access to any form of router except my Debian 9 gateway servers (192.168.X.1/24 and [DCX.pub.ip.v4])

I'm planning on using openVPN and route private traffic through the vpn network. Is there any better solution? (Better as in "more secure/faster")

It sounds like a basic thing I should know, however I don't.. :/